# Python twisted manhole that works like ipython or similar

Tags: python, twisted

Running this I found off the web

```
#manhole
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.manhole import telnet
def createShellServer( ):
    print 'Creating shell server instance'
    factory = telnet.ShellFactory()
    port = reactor.listenTCP( 2000, factory)
    factory.namespace['x'] = application
    factory.namespace['s'] = s
    factory.username = 'me'
    factory.password = 'me'
    print 'Listening on port 2000'
    return port
```

This worked, I was able to manhole into my twisted application. But I can't up-arrow to get the previous commands, nor does it have any tab completion. I think just being able to go through the history would be a big help.

This is very new stuff to me. So I think I could be using an old method to manhole in. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the old, deprecated, essentially unmaintained implementation of manhole.

Instead, you should be using [the one included in Twisted Conch](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.conch.manhole.html).  You can find examples of its use along with the [other Twisted Conch examples](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/conch/examples/).