# Provide remote shell for Python script

Tags: python, ipython

I want to create a convenient simple way to connect to my running Python script remotely (via file sockets, TCP or whatever) to get a remote interactive shell.

I thought that this would be easy via IPython or so. However, I didn't really found any good example. I tried to start `IPython.embed_kernel()`, but that is blocking. So I tried to run that in another thread but that had many strange side effects on the rest of my script and I don't want any side effects (no replacement of `sys.stdout`, `sys.stderr`, `sys.excepthook` or whatever) and it also didn't worked - I could not connect. I found [this related bug report](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/4032) and [this code snippet](https://github.com/msabramo/pyramid_ipython_kernel/blob/master/pyramid_ipython_kernel.py) which suggest to use `mock.patch('signal.signal')` but that also didn't worked. Also, why do I need that - I also don't want IPython to register any signal handlers.

There are also hacks such as [pyringe](https://github.com/google/pyringe) and my own [pydbattach](https://github.com/albertz/pydbattach) to attach to some running Python instance but they seem to be too hacky.

Maybe [QdbRemotePythonDebugger](https://code.google.com/p/rad2py/wiki/QdbRemotePythonDebugger) can help me?

Comment: Sometimes blocking is acceptable and external thread doesn't work, see  (my question) [How can I get tab-completion to work in gdb's Python-interactive (pi) shell? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70231270/how-can-i-get-tab-completion-to-work-in-gdbs-python-interactive-pi-shell/70241082#70241082) for some alternative methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My current solution is to setup an IPython ZMQ kernel. I don't just use

```
IPython.embed_kernel()
```

because that has many side effects, such as messing around with `sys.stdout`, `sys.stderr`, `sys.excepthook`, `signal.signal`, etc and I don't want these side effects. Also, `embed_kernel()` is blocking and doesn't really work out-of-the-box in a separate thread (see [here](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/4032)).

So, I came up with this code, which is far too complicated in my opinion. (That is why I created a feature request [here](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/8097).)

```
def initIPythonKernel():
  # You can remotely connect to this kernel. See the output on stdout.
  try:
    import IPython.kernel.zmq.ipkernel
    from IPython.kernel.zmq.ipkernel import Kernel
    from IPython.kernel.zmq.heartbeat import Heartbeat
    from IPython.kernel.zmq.session import Session
    from IPython.kernel import write_connection_file
    import zmq
    from zmq.eventloop import ioloop
    from zmq.eventloop.zmqstream import ZMQStream
    IPython.kernel.zmq.ipkernel.signal = lambda sig, f: None  # Overwrite.
  except ImportError, e:
    print "IPython import error, cannot start IPython kernel. %s" % e
    return
  import atexit
  import socket
  import logging
  import threading

  # Do in mainthread to avoid history sqlite DB errors at exit.
  # https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/680
  assert isinstance(threading.currentThread(), threading._MainThread)
  try:
    connection_file = "kernel-%s.json" % os.getpid()
    def cleanup_connection_file():
      try:
        os.remove(connection_file)
      except (IOError, OSError):
        pass
    atexit.register(cleanup_connection_file)

    logger = logging.Logger("IPython")
    logger.addHandler(logging.NullHandler())
    session = Session(username=u'kernel')

    context = zmq.Context.instance()
    ip = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
    transport = "tcp"
    addr = "%s://%s" % (transport, ip)
    shell_socket = context.socket(zmq.ROUTER)
    shell_port = shell_socket.bind_to_random_port(addr)
    iopub_socket = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
    iopub_port = iopub_socket.bind_to_random_port(addr)
    control_socket = context.socket(zmq.ROUTER)
    control_port = control_socket.bind_to_random_port(addr)

    hb_ctx = zmq.Context()
    heartbeat = Heartbeat(hb_ctx, (transport, ip, 0))
    hb_port = heartbeat.port
    heartbeat.start()

    shell_stream = ZMQStream(shell_socket)
    control_stream = ZMQStream(control_socket)

    kernel = Kernel(session=session,
                    shell_streams=[shell_stream, control_stream],
                    iopub_socket=iopub_socket,
                    log=logger)

    write_connection_file(connection_file,
                          shell_port=shell_port, iopub_port=iopub_port, control_port=control_port, hb_port=hb_port,
                          ip=ip)

    print "To connect another client to this IPython kernel, use:", \
          "ipython console --existing %s" % connection_file
  except Exception, e:
    print "Exception while initializing IPython ZMQ kernel. %s" % e
    return

  def ipython_thread():
    kernel.start()
    try:
      ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
      pass

  thread = threading.Thread(target=ipython_thread, name="IPython kernel")
  thread.daemon = True
  thread.start()
```

Note that this code is outdated now. I have made a package [here](https://github.com/albertz/background-zmq-ipython) which should contain a more recent version, and which can be installed via pip.

---

Other alternatives to attach to running CPython process without having it prepared beforehand. Those usually use the OS debugging capabilities (or use gdb/lldb) to attach to the native CPython process and then inject some code or just analyze the native CPython thread stacks.

- [pyringe](https://github.com/google/pyringe)
- [pyrasite](https://github.com/lmacken/pyrasite)
- [pystuck](https://github.com/alonho/pystuck)
- [pdb-clone](https://code.google.com/p/pdb-clone/wiki/RemoteDebugging)

Here are other alternatives where you prepare your Python script beforehand to listen on some (tcp/file) socket to provide an interface for remote debugging and/or just a Python shell / REPL.

- [winpdb](http://winpdb.org/) (cross platform) remote debugger
- [PyCharm IDE](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) remote debugger,
  [doc](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/remote-debugging.html)
- [PyDev IDE](http://pydev.org/) remote debugger
- [Twisted Conch Manhole](https://twistedmatrix.com),
  [official example](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/_downloads/demo_manhole.tac),
  [lothar.com example](http://www.lothar.com/tech/twisted/manhole.xhtml),
  [lysator.liu.se example](http://www.lysator.liu.se/xenofarm/python/tmp-server/Twisted/doc/howto/manhole.html),
  [related StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24296807/python-twisted-manhole-that-works-like-ipython-or-similar),
  [blog.futurefoundries.com (2013)](http://blog.futurefoundries.com/2013/04/ssh-into-your-python-server.html)
- very simple [manhole](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/manhole), has also some overview over related projects
- [ispyd](https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/ispyd)
- [Eric IDE](http://eric-ide.python-projects.org/)
- [Trepan (based on pydb)](https://github.com/rocky/python2-trepan)
- [rpdb](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rpdb/)
- [rconsole](http://winpdb.org/2010/09/rconsole-remote-python-console/)
  (part of [rfoo](http://code.google.com/p/rfoo/))

Some overviews and collected code examples:

- [(QGIS) Example code for PyDev, Winpdb, Eric](https://github.com/sourcepole/qgis-remote-debug)
- [Python Wiki: Python debugging tools](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDebuggingTools),
  [Python Wiki: Python debuggers](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDebuggers)

(This overview is from [here](https://github.com/albertz/pydbattach).)

Comment: God job ! this will help me a lot (embeded in a tkinter app). I will add `from jupyter_core.paths import jupyter_runtime_dir` to write file in a more accesible dir.